# After installing docker in mac with boot2docker, The below error appears. How can i workaround it?

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

**Error message:**

> Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.15)

**My client docker version details are below:**

```
$ docker version

Client version: 1.6.0

Client API version: 1.18

Go version (client): go1.4.2

Git commit (client): 4749651

OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64

FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.15)
```

**And my boot2docker version details are :**

```
$ boot2docker version

Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.6.0
```

How can I workaround this error?

Comment: Seems i have same client version , and boot2docker version with me?

Answer (score 0):

Checked the docker version inside boot2docker by ssh ing into boot2docker VM

1. boot2docker ssh
2. inside docker env checked "docker version"

Found that its different.

Workaround:

1. Removed the VM by : boot2docker delete
2. Removed VM files by : rm -r ~/.boot2docker
3. Re installed boot2docker.
4. boot2docker init
5. boot2docker up

Checked again the clint and server versions, and seems its the same. And the error never appeared again.